# Get owner / user of a cronjob

Tags: shell, cron

In Linux (Mint / Ubuntu), I can create cronjobs for each user individually. Is there any way, I can find out the name of the user against whome the cronjob is running. I want to get the username of cronjob owner in a shell script which is going to cron'd...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Get the script's owner

On any system with as `stat` that is compatible with modern GNU `stat`, the user ID of the owner of the script is:

```
stat -c %u "$0"
```

The user name of the owner of the script is:

```
stat -c %U "$0"
```

In general on linux, `stat -c %U file` returns the owner of `file`.  We substitute in `$0` because that variable typically contains the name of current script file.

#### Getting effective user ID of the user running the script

To get the effective user ID number of the user running a script, use `id -u`:

```
$ id -u
1001
```

To save it in a variable

```
$ uid=$(id -u)
$ echo "$uid"
1001
```

If the script is running under `bash`, then the effective user ID is stored in the shell variable `EUID`:

```
$ echo $EUID
1001
```

On many systems, the default is for cronjobs to run under `dash` which does not support `EUID`.  Thus, it is safer and more reliable to use `id -u` as shown above.

Use the `-n` option in addition to the `-u` option to get the user name:

```
$ id -un
john1024
```

Answer (score 1):

`man 5 crontab` suggests that a cronjob will find the owning user's username in the `LOGNAME` environment variable:

> Several environment variables are set up automatically by the cron(8) daemon.  `SHELL` is set to `/bin/sh`, and  `LOGNAME`  and
>          `HOME`  are  set  from  the  `/etc/passwd` line of the crontab´s owner.  `HOME` and `SHELL` can be overridden by settings in the
>          crontab; `LOGNAME` can not.
>
> (Note: the `LOGNAME` variable is sometimes called `USER` on BSD systems and is also automatically set).